# Google Tag Manager: How to add list of IDs for custom trigger

Tags: triggers, google-tag-manager

How do I add a list of ids for a custom trigger? I have ~15 ids that I would like to form a custom trigger but don't want to add each one of them separately.

Is there a way to do something like `id contains ('123', '456', '789')`
[GTM screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da5J4.png)

I tried to enter a list in the contains function, but the tag did not fire.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is with regEx (regular expressions).

Something like `(123|456|789)` will match all all three of those values. This is the easiest way to apply a filter with multiple matches. If your values are more complex than that, you can also use nested matching groups and or tokens to further enhance your expression.

RegEx is a very deep topic and can get rather complicated. I suggest learning about it and the nuances. I prefer regex101.com but there are a ton of resources available.